# Connecting phone using copper power wires

Tags: signal, communication, wire, telephone

I want to install a video door phone (intercom) in my home, for this I have done a pre-wiring of 4 individual copper wires (normally used for home electricity) and the total length of wires is about 60 feet.

Following are the details:

**Intercom Model**: Panasonic VL-SW250BX [Intercom Details](http://www.panasonic.com/in/business/security-systems/accessories-others/video-intercom/vl-sw250bx.html)

From main monitor to door station, **required  DC voltage is 20V and current is 190ma and (5V DC, 2 mA standby)** according to the door station back label image [Door-station-back-label](http://cache1.smarthome.com/images/52283side3big.jpg)

**Recommended wiring by the manufacturer**: CAT3 24Awg with maximum length of 350 feet

**My wiring setup**: Un-twisted 4 parallel individual copper wires (normally used for home 
electricity)

I would like to know if my system will using these wires or if I need to change my wiring.

**Update** Just for information: I took the risk of installation and fortunately the system worked with a little noise in picture.
I will follow  W5VO advice to put some ferrites around the power wires near the intercom
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: What kind of wiring does the intercom recommend?

Comment: it recommends: CAT3 24AWG

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! For you to get the best answers it is important that you provide all of the important details. For example, can you give a manufacturer and model number for the intercom? Can you tell us what sort of signals or power will be carried by these wires?

Comment: Cat 3 is twisted pair.  Is the wiring you installed twisted pair also?

Comment: @user28910  wiring I installed is Un-twisted 4 parallel individual copper wires (normally used for home electricity)

Comment: @JoeHass I have updated my question with all details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those two terminals that you show in your picture are the **only** connectors, then you should be fine. The intercom specification indicates that it is a wireless video system, so all device communication is probably happening somewhere on 2.4 GHz. Those screw terminals, and the fact that there are only two terminals, along with the power requirements being listed, are pretty good indicators that those wires carry **only** power. If it carries *only* power, then your normal house wiring will carry power just fine. If the video signal is carried by the wires, then they probably would be using the cable as network wiring and the house wiring might not work.

A caveat: The twisted wire that they specify will give you some noise rejection that the regular untwisted house wiring will not. If your intercom design is somewhat marginal, then you may have random interference. You could mitigate this by putting some ferrites around the power wires near the intercom, and possibly twisting the two power wires in the run.

Note that this is all independent of any building code requirements your building may be required to meet.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The system is a **NOT** wireless system. The door station connecting wires will carry video+audio as well as DC power from/to the main  monitor. The wireless part is limited to a additional handset which is a cordless for the main monitor.

so from your view Can I say that the system will work but may have some noise in audio/video?

Comment: @Deepak Then I would recommend rewiring with the specified wire.

Comment: So From your view Can I say that the system will work but may have some noise in audio/video? or it will not work at all?

Comment: It might work, but there's a good chance that it won't. Electrically, there's no impedance matching, and if your intercom is using it as a 10 Mbit Ethernet link then it is easy to see it fail completely. I think it's difficult to tell if it would work or what the failure mode would be based on the information available.

Comment: ok can you please let me know that what additional information you need, I can search for it